# How to save a component in a Const and render it?

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react and basically I want that depending on a condition (I put something simple), a component that I have created called `<Button>` is rendered or the default `<button>` of `HTML` is rendered.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, in any case it doesn't work, nothing is displayed.

This is my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
export const Button = ({ children }) => {
  return <button>{children}</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  let Component = "";
  if (1 + 1 == 2) {
    Component = <Button />;
  } else {
    Component = "button";
  }

  return <Component>I am a button</Component>;
}
```

This is my live code:

[my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-currying-jrjlhq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Component = <Button />;` to `Component = Button;`.

`Button` is a function, `<Button />` is an element. When you use `<Component>I am a button</Component>`, JSX expects `Component` to be a functional component or class component, not a JSX element.